# Why does GMRES converge much slower for large Dirichlet boundary conditions?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, finite-differences

I'm trying to numerically solve a simple Laplace equation in 2D, with a nonlinear source term:

$\nabla^2 u = u^2$

with boundary conditions as $u=0$ everywhere except for $y=1$ where $u=u_0$. I'm using `scipy`'s `newton_krylov` solver (`method="lgmres"`) to minimized the discretized equation using the finite-difference method.

Here's the problem: for relatively small values of $u_0$ such as $u_0=1$, LGMRES converges relatively fast with fewer than 7 iterations. However, when I increase $u_0$ to $10$ or $100$, the the solver converges much slower and needs on the order of O(1000) iterations to converge.

Is this an expected behaviour of Newton-Krylov solvers? If so, what can I do to alleviate the issue?

Comment: Probably better to ask this on [scicomp.stackexchange](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: This shouldn't be so surprising, the nonlinearity is more significant when $u_0$ is bigger.